# xcode - set value of a nested object

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I have a  json from a service and I need to change the values of one obeject.

```
 {
        question =     (
                    {
                answer =             (
                                    {
                        Id = 1;
                        value = 1;
                    },
                                    {
                        Id = 2;
                        value = 0;
                    }
                );
            },
    .....
```

I use that code to directly access to the second "value" element and set it to "true"

```
 NSMutableDictionary * dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *preguntasDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    preguntasDict      =[[[dict valueForKey:@"question"]mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *answer = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    respuestasDict     =[[[[preguntasDict valueForKey:@"answer"]objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:1] mutableCopy];
    [respuestasDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] forKey:@"value"];
```

It works: "respuestasDict" changes but the whoole "dict" not.

My question is: how could rebuild the entire dictionary? or it is possible to access directly to the nested object and change it?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `perguntasDict` and `respuestasDict` are mutable copies of your dictionaries, so basically you are editing copies of your `dict`. You need to access `dict` directly, like this:

```
NSArray *answers = dict[@"question"][@"answer"];
[answers firstObject][@"value"] = @(YES);
```

PS: Doing dict[@"question"] is the same thing as `[dict objectForKey:@"question"]`. Also, `@(YES)` is the same thing as `[NSNumber numberWithBool:true]`

Comment: Tx for answer. I tried accessing directly to dict but without mutable copy,. app crash (without a readable compiler message).

Comment: @doxsi try adding an exception breakpoint to see where it crashes - http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions